# How to build XML Tree in c# with the available structure of XML Tree

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, list, path

I have list of paths which is a 'List(Of String)'and I want to create xml tree accordingly.

For Example: Let's say I have 10 paths as following

1. a/b.book
2. a/b/c.book
3. a/b/c/d/e.page
4. a/b/c/d/f.page
5. a/b/g.book
6. a/b/g/h/i.page
7. a/b/g/h/j.page
8. k/l.book
9. k/l/m/n.page
10. o/p.book

My Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map>
<book navtitle = "a">
   <book navtitle = "b">
      <book navtitle = "c">
         <book navtitle = "d">
            <page navtitle = "e"/>
            <page navtitle = "f"/>
         </book>
      </book>
      <book navtitle = "g">
         <book navtitle = "h">
            <page navtitle = "i"/>
            <page navtitle = "j"/>
         </book>
      </book>
   </book>
</book>

<book navtitle = "k">
   <book navtitle = "l">
      <book navtitle = "m">
         <page navtitle = "n"/>
      </book>
   </book>
</book>

<book navtitle = "o">
   <book navtitle = "p">
   </book>
</book>
</map>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following recursive algorithm using Xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net;


namespace ConsoleApplication157
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] inputs = {
                                  "a/b.book",
                                  "a/b/c.book",
                                  "a/b/c/d/e.page",
                                  "a/b/c/d/f.page",
                                  "a/b/g.book",
                                  "a/b/g/h/i.page",
                                  "a/b/g/h/j.page",
                                  "k/l.book",
                                  "k/l/m/n.page",
                                  "o/p.book"
                              };
            List<List<string>> splitArrays = inputs.Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '/', '.' }).ToList()).ToList();

            XElement root = new XElement("root");
            GetTree(root, splitArrays);

        }
        static void GetTree(XElement parent, List<List<string>> splitArrays)
        {
            var groups = splitArrays.OrderBy(x => x[0]).GroupBy(x => new { path = x.First(), type = x.Last() }).ToArray();
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                List<List<string>> children = null;
                XElement element = new XElement(group.Key.type, new XAttribute("navtitle", group.Key.path));
                parent.Add(element);
                Boolean first = true;
                foreach (var child in group.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count))
                {
                    if (child.Count() == 2) //since we sorts by count, 1 indicates we are at the leaf
                    {
                        if (first)
                        {
                            if (children != null)
                            {
                                GetTree(element, children);
                                children = null;
                            }
                            first = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //remove first index of each splitArray
                        if (children == null) children = new List<List<string>>();
                        List<string> newChild = child.Skip(1).ToList();
                        children.Add(newChild);
                    }

                }
                //when there are no elements with count = 1 then call Getree here
                if (children != null)
                {
                    GetTree(element, children);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It might look something like this recursive method.

```
Private Sub BuildTrie(path As String,
                      trie As XElement)
    Dim p As List(Of String)
    p = path.Split(New Char() {"/"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList
    If p.Count > 0 Then
        Dim thisP As String = p(0)
        If thisP <> "" Then
            p.RemoveAt(0)
            Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
            ie = From el In trie.Elements Where el.@navtitle = thisP Select el Take 1

            Dim thisND As XElement
            If ie.Count = 1 Then
                thisND = ie(0)
            Else
                thisND = <book navtitle=""></book>
                thisND.@navtitle = thisP
                trie.Add(thisND)
            End If
            If p.Count > 0 Then BuildTrie(String.Join("/"c, p), thisND)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

to see it how it works try this

```
    Dim pths() As String = {"a/b/c", "a/b/c/d/f", "a/b/g", "a/b/g/h", "k/l", "k/l/m/n", "o/p"}
    Dim _trie As XElement = <books></books>
    For Each p As String In pths
        BuildTrie(p, _trie)
    Next

    Stop ' look at _trie
```

This isn't complete but maybe it will give you some ideas.

edit:  Output from above.

```
<books>
  <book navtitle="a">
    <book navtitle="b">
      <book navtitle="c">
        <book navtitle="d">
          <book navtitle="f"></book>
        </book>
      </book>
      <book navtitle="g">
        <book navtitle="h"></book>
      </book>
    </book>
  </book>
  <book navtitle="k">
    <book navtitle="l">
      <book navtitle="m">
        <book navtitle="n"></book>
      </book>
    </book>
  </book>
  <book navtitle="o">
    <book navtitle="p"></book>
  </book>
</books>
```

Answer (score 1):

You commented that you are `"Trying to build xml tree without usage of xmlelement or xmldocument"`, which I can appreciate. I would like to submit another option which is .NET classes and Xml Serialization.

First, we start by creating classes which can represent your data. Since it's a simple design, the classes are simple

```vb
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<XmlRoot("map")>
Public Class book
    <XmlAttribute> Public Property navtitle As String
    <XmlElement("book")> Public books As List(Of book)
    <XmlElement("page")> Public pages As List(Of page)
End Class

Public Class page
    <XmlAttribute> Public Property navtitle As String
End Class
```

To demonstrate how you can build your classes manually, here is some code, which is all on one line, and although difficult to read, should be fairly easy to see how it matches your xml file

```vb
Private Function createMap() As book
    Dim m As New book() With {
        .books = New List(Of book)() From {
            New book() With {.navtitle = "a",
                .books = New List(Of book)() From {
                    New book() With {.navtitle = "b",
                        .books = New List(Of book)() From {
                            New book With {.navtitle = "c",
                                .books = New List(Of book)() From {
                                    New book With {.navtitle = "d",
                                        .pages = New List(Of page)() From {
                                            New page With {.navtitle = "e"},
                                            New page With {.navtitle = "f"}}}}}}}}},
            New book() With {.navtitle = "g",
                .books = New List(Of book)() From {
                    New book() With {.navtitle = "h",
                        .pages = New List(Of page)() From {
                            New page() With {.navtitle = "i"},
                            New page() With {.navtitle = "j"}}}}},
            New book With {.navtitle = "k",
                .books = New List(Of book)() From {
                    New book() With {.navtitle = "l",
                        .books = New List(Of book)() From {
                            New book() With {.navtitle = "m",
                                .pages = New List(Of page)() From {
                                    New page With {.navtitle = "n"}}}}}}},
            New book With {.navtitle = "o",
                .books = New List(Of book)() From {
                    New book() With {.navtitle = "p"}}}}}
    Return m
End Function
```

This function returns an object which holds all your data, with strong typing. This object can be written to an Xml file via Xml Serialization simply

```vb
Private Sub createXmlFile(path As String, b As book)
    Dim s As New XmlSerializer(GetType(book))
    Using sw As New StreamWriter(path)
        s.Serialize(sw, b)
    End Using
End Sub
```

```vb
Dim m = createMap()
createXmlFile("path.xml", m)
```

So we have the framework for your classes, and for writing them to Xml, but no dynamic interpreter. Here is an interpreter

```vb
Private Function createMap(titles As IEnumerable(Of String)) As book
    Dim root As New book()
    For Each title In titles
        Dim book = root
        Dim parts = title.Split("/"c)
        For Each part In parts
            Dim b As book
            If part.Contains(".") Then
                If part.Contains("page") Then
                    If book.pages Is Nothing Then book.pages = New List(Of page)()
                    book.pages.Add(New page() With {.navtitle = part.Split("."c).First()})
                Else
                    If book.books Is Nothing Then book.books = New List(Of book)()
                    book.books.Add(New book() With {.navtitle = part.Split("."c).First()})
                End If
            Else
                If book.books?.Any(Function(x) x.navtitle = part.First()) Then
                    b = book.books.Single(Function(x) x.navtitle = part.First())
                Else
                    b = New book() With {.navtitle = part.First()}
                    If book.books Is Nothing Then book.books = New List(Of book)()
                    book.books.Add(b)
                End If
                book = b
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return root
End Function
```

Note it is not recursive, but it could be written using recursion if you like, but it's not necessary. Now we can call that function overload instead, and pass in your paths. We use `IEnumerable(Of String)` instead of List because you should almost only use List when you intend it to be modified, such as reordered. Plus, `IEnumerable(Of String)` will accept many different types - such as the array below

```vb
Dim m = createMap(
    {"a/b.book",
    "a/b/c.book",
    "a/b/c/d/e.page",
    "a/b/c/d/f.page",
    "a/b/g.book",
    "a/b/g/h/i.page",
    "a/b/g/h/j.page",
    "k/l.book",
    "k/l/m/n.page",
    "o/p.book"})
createXmlFile("path1.xml", m)
```

And your file is created

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<map xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <book navtitle="a">
    <book navtitle="b">
      <book navtitle="c">
        <book navtitle="d">
          <page navtitle="e" />
          <page navtitle="f" />
        </book>
      </book>
      <book navtitle="g">
        <book navtitle="h">
          <page navtitle="i" />
          <page navtitle="j" />
        </book>
      </book>
    </book>
  </book>
  <book navtitle="k">
    <book navtitle="l">
      <book navtitle="m">
        <page navtitle="n" />
      </book>
    </book>
  </book>
  <book navtitle="o">
    <book navtitle="p" />
  </book>
</map>
```

Bonus: Xml Serialization also makes reading Xml files much easier

```vb
Private Function readXmlFile(path As String) As book
    Dim b As book
    Dim s As New XmlSerializer(GetType(book))
    Using sr As New StreamReader(path)
        b = DirectCast(s.Deserialize(sr), book)
    End Using
    Return b
End Function
```

```vb
Dim m = readXmlFile("path1.xml")
```

and `m` holds the exact same map which we had previously created and written to the file.